# Método static void no funciona

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse

```
   public static String suma() {

        int numMedio1;
        int numMedio2;
        int nuevoDen;
        int nuevoNum;

        nuevoDen = denom1 * denom2;

        numMedio1 = (nuevoDen / denom1) * numerador1;
        numMedio2 = (nuevoDen / denom2) * numerador2;

        nuevoNum = numMedio1 + numMedio2;

        if(nuevoNum == nuevoDen) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "1");

        }else {

            reducir(nuevoNum, nuevoDen);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nuevoNum + "/" + nuevoDen);

        }

        return "";

    }
```

```
public static void reducir(int x, int y) {

        while (x % 10000 == 0 && y % 10000 == 0) {

            x = x / 10000;
            y = y / 10000;

        }
```

Hola, tengo el problema de que intento llamar un void llamado reducción con los parámetros x e y, reemplazándolos por dos variables de otro método llamado suma, que básicamente se encarga de sumar dos fracciones, pero esto por algún motivo no funciona. El problema es claramente el void, porque si tomo el código de ese método y en vez de usar x e y, utilizo nuevoNum y nuevoDen, funciona perfectamente.
¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias.

Comment: Tengo varias dudas, que valores estas ingresando a tus variables en el método `suma() `?  Por qué no utilizas un método para numero (int, soble, float) y cuál es el propósito de querer que retorne un valor de tipo String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de tu método reducir es que no modifica ni `x` ni `y` (ya que en Java los parámetros se pasan por valor en lugar de ser pasados por referencia). Esto quiere decir que el valor de x e y cuando el método acabe de ejecutarse va a quedarse igual que estaba antes de llamar al método.

El método tampoco devuelve nada, por lo que tampoco puedes guardar los cambios de esta forma. Para más "inri" necesitas devolver dos valores en lugar de uno.

Hay varias maneras de solucionar esto, una podría ser la siguiente. En primer lugar definir una pequeña clase que contenga los dos valores:

```
public class Par {

  private final int x;

  private final int y;

  public Par(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public getY() {
    return y;
  }


}
```

Ahora puedes definir tu método así:

```
public static Par reducir(int x, int y) {
  while (x % 10000 == 0 && y % 10000 == 0) {
    x = x / 10000;
    y = y / 10000;
  }
  return new Par(x, y);
}
```

Y llamarlo así:

```
Par par = reducir(nuevoNum, nuevoDen);
nuevoNum = par.getX();
nuevoDen = par.getY();
```

Más info sobre el paso de parámetros por valor/referencia:

- http://www.clubdetecnologia.net/blog/2017/java-paso-de-valores-por-referencia-o-por-valor/